# Referencing without executing

Tags: lambda, java-8, method-reference

According to this [article](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/java-8-method-references-explained-5-minutes/), the method reference is defined as a method or constructor that is referenced without being executed, can anyone explain how is that possible?

For example:

```
public void main String(args[]) {
     List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
     // Below is a method reference that is referenced and being executed on run (prints the numbers!!)
     numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If anyone can explain what statement 'referenced without being executed' means, it would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

When you call `numbers.forEach(System.out::println)`, you reference the `System.out::println` method, but not execute it. For example, if `numbers` list is empty, then this method will never be executed. On the other hand, having this method reference, the `forEach` method can internally call this reference as many times as it want (in this case: for every list element).

Probably it would be easier to understand when you rewrite this code with equivalent anonymous class:

```
 numbers.forEach(new Consumer<Integer>() {
     public void accept(Integer num) {
         System.out.println(num);
     }
 });
```

Here you can see that method reference is actually creation of helper object of `Consumer` type, without actually calling the referenced method.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement `numbers.forEach(System.out::println);` is an inlined version of

```
Consumer<Integer> c=System.out::println;
numbers.forEach(c);
```

This should better illustrate that the first line creates a reference to the method `println` of the instance of a `PrintWriter` found in `System.out` and doesn’t executed it. It doesn’t print anything—it wouldn’t even know what to print. The object to be printed is a parameter of the created `Consumer`’s [`accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-) method.

The second line `numbers.forEach(c)` will eventually print every number, because the specified `Consumer` has been created as a reference `System.out::println`. The `forEach` method receives an arbitrary `Consumer` and will perform it’s encapsulated action for every element by invoking said `accept` method for each element, passing the element as an argument.

Of course, you can inline the variable `c` getting your original statement `numbers.forEach(System.out::println);`, but then, difference between the consumer creation and execution is not so obvious, but also not that relevant for this use case. In general, you could keep the `Consumer` much longer than for a single use case.